# Add new Uploader to Ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor5

How is this possible add new uploader functionality to ckeditor5 like upload audio or video?

I tried for using [ckeditor5](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_upload_ui_filedialogbuttonview-FileDialogButtonView.html) doc but it is not clear at all.
I using this vue file for using ckeditor5. in this file, I use a customized uploadadapter for my project, but now I don't know how i can upload another type of file like audio and video in this attitude

```
<script>
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor';
    import MyUploadAdapter from '../adapter/UploadAdapter';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                instance: null,
                article: {
                    data: '',
                },
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.initialize();
        },

        methods: {
            // Initializing Editor
            initialize: function () {
                ClassicEditor
                    .create(document.querySelector("#editor"), this.config)
                    .then(editor => {
                        // get initial instance object of editor
                        this.instance = editor;

                        // set initial binder of editor on start
                        editor.model.document.on('change', () => {
                            this.valueBinder(editor.getData())
                        });

                        editor.plugins.get('FileDialogButtonView')


                        // This place loads the adapter.
                        editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader, article) => {
                            return new MyUploadAdapter(loader, this.article);

                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            },

            }
        },
    }

</script>
```

Comment: use @ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload

Comment: tnx for your respond, I use Vue and @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic, Would you tell me how I can do that please?

Comment: do you want develop ckeditor with simple javascript, right?

Comment: yes @KaushikAndani, I add my code buddy...

Answer (score 0):

For Upload file you can use [CKFinder](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/adapter-ckfinder.html).

For the configuration of CKfinder, Please refer this [link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_adapter-ckfinder_uploadadapter-CKFinderAdapterConfig.html).

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( editorElement, {
        ckfinder: {
            uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json' // here you can set your own file path
        }
    } )
    .then( ... )
    .catch( ... );
```

Comment: Tnx buddy, but how I add different button for audio

Comment: @Kamran_dev sorry for late reply, for audio button i will update you once i done with my research